# How does a MVC 3 View get binded to a Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, controller

This is more like a "Architectural Understanding" of how MVC 3 works. I really want to know how does the MVC knows which view to call for a given controller action. I can guess that when we use the Visual Studio to create a view for a controller action, it stores these bindings in some sort of file on the project, is that right?

Thanks in advance.
Marcelo Myara
Rio de Janeiro/Brazil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done using the idea of ["Convention over Configuration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

If you use a random action that doesn't have a view, you can see that it's actually trying a bunch of different conventions, looking for a match:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionWithNoView()
{
    return View();
}
```

It looks for a view file (.aspx, .ascx, .cshtml, or .vbhtml extension) matching the action name in the **Views/ControllerName** or **Views/Shared** folder.

> The view 'SomeActionWithNoView' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Home/SomeActionWithNoView.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Home/SomeActionWithNoView.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/SomeActionWithNoView.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/SomeActionWithNoView.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Home/SomeActionWithNoView.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Home/SomeActionWithNoView.vbhtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/SomeActionWithNoView.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/SomeActionWithNoView.vbhtml

---

A default view Layout can be set using **_ViewStart.cshtml** in the **/Views** root:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyDefaultLayout.cshtml";
}
```

It can be removed or changed as needed in the individual views.

Comment: Hummm... I see. But, in that case (without any table to map them), how does a View knows what layout it should be rendered upon (like, how does a view knows to render upon ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml)?

Comment: @MarceloMyara the layout is set manually -- there's no convention.  Typically you use **_ViewStart.cshtml** to specify a common layout, then override it as needed in the individual views.

Comment: Yeah. Ok, now it all came together in my mind! Thanks a lot man!!